# Disable KMS on Debian Sid

Tags: debian, grub, suspend, initramfs, kms

I've recently started having trouble resuming my Sid laptop from suspend. I'm not sure if this was caused by an upgrade or by me tinkering to try and get a splash screen working, but anyway, I have my suspicions that it may be caused by KMS (Kernel Modesetting).
Unfortunately, I can't seem to turn KMS off. Can anybody help?

Here's what I have already tried:

- Booting with the `nomodeset` option in GRUB (actually, this is set by default)
- Removing all boot options other than `nomodeset`
- Removing the line `i915 modeset=1` from `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and running `update-initramfs`